# MVC 4 Routing , Get/Post requests handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm faced with the following problem :

I have a controller with lets say the following actions:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

            return View("Index", viewModel);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public void ExportToExcell(LeadsViewModel model)
        {
            // Export to excell code goes here
        }
```

The problem is the following:

The User enters on Index page with this URL : /Controller/Index

Then the user submits the form to Action ExportToExcel

Data is exported to Excel( file downloaded ) and it's okay.

The URL becomes /Controller/ExportToExcell

Then when I am clicking "Enter" I am going To /Controller/ExportToExcell but with GET
and of course falling with Page Not Found, the question is how properly to Deal with this in MVC

Comment: Could you share your ExportToExcell action? (this is not about your question. I want to use something like this. I write an export action but mine is not working. If yours is working, I can use it.) Thanks.

Comment: It's code from third party dll that our team developed. It is creating xml file that Excel can read it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use  `void` as returned type of your post action, use an `ActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToExcell(LeadsViewModel model)
{
   // Export to excell code goes here
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Is Return View("SomeView",viewModel) is also bad practice , coz the thing will happen ... I meam I have action called Foo(){ return View("Index",new ViewModel() } Am I Always need to use return View(viewModel) that suits the route name , and in other cases use RedirectToAction

Comment: @StringBuilder You should google for PRG (POST-REDIRECT-GET) pattern, it's quite interesting and... a rather good idea (my point of view) in MVC apps. See for example http://blog.jorritsalverda.nl/2010/03/10/maintainable-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your problem is that you aren't returning a FileResult, and the browser will redirect you to your post path. Can't test it right now, but I believe the following should work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToExcell(LeadsViewModel model)
{
   // Generate the Excel file into a MemoryStream for example

   // Return a FileResult with the Excel mime type
   return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "MyExcelFile.xls");
}
```

Check [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and [Controller.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for more details.

As a note, I'm not completely sure if that's the mime type for an Excel file, but if you say you are already downloading the file, your probably already have it :)

Answer (score 0):

You must return ActionResult instead of void.

```
 public ActionResult ExportToExcel(PagingParams args)
    {
        var data = new StudentDataContext().Student.Take(200).ToList();
        return data.GridExportToExcel<Student>("GridExcel.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Excel2007, args.ExportOption);
    }
```

Please check the link: [Export Action](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/Exporting/GridExport)